# How to expose an array of UDTs through a property?

Tags: vb6

I have a class `cDept` which has a UDT defined.

```
public type udtEmp
    Name as string
    Id as long 
end type
```

I have an array defined:

```
private m_Emps() as udtEmp
```

I want to expose the array through a property.  I tried the following:

```
Public Property Get Employees() As udtEmp()
    Employees= m_Emps
End Property
```

So far everything compiles. Now I instantiate the class and try to access the property.

```
dim myUdt as udtEmp
dim oDept as cDept
set oDept = new cDept

myUdt = oDept.Employees(1) ' -- error
```

I get an error stating `Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment`.

What am I missing?

Comment: Did you really intend to return the whole array?  If you are trying to access just one element at a time, take a look at @MarkL answer.

Answer (score 4):

(Not tested)
I think your property access is trying to use the '1' as an argument to the property (which has no arguments), thus the 'wrong number' error.  Rather than trying to property get the array and then index access the array, will it work to have the property get (or a different one) return the desired array element?

```
Public Property Get Employees(ndx as long) As udtEmp
    Employees= m_Emps(ndx)
End Property
```